# Auto join Facebook in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I want to create a PHP script which allow me fill the Group ID then it will join to Facebook Group automatically.
API is not supported. Can you give me an idea? PHP or JS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for it, and everything else would not be allowed. In other words: it´s not possible.

Comment: Some one create a tool can do it. So do you have know any idea to join it?

Comment: it´s not allowed, that´s the important part of my answer. if someone created a tool for it, you should report it to facebook.